# magento cart product's wont stack

Tags: php, magento, cart, product

I added an observer on `checkout_cart_product_add_after` containing this code:

```
public function addToCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart'); //Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem(); // Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item
        $quote = $item->getQuote(); // Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
        $product = $item->getProduct(); // Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
        $cart->init();

        $item = $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $_product = $product->getTypeId() == "configurable" ? $item->getOptionByCode('simple_product')->getProduct() : $product;
        $_product->setIsSuperMode(true);
        $item->setProduct($_product);
        $item->setQty(1);
        $item->save();
        $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
        $quote->collectTotals();
        $cart->save();

        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);

        return $this;
    }
```

It always adds the simple product to cart, not the configurable.
It is working, except for one thing, they don't stack on eachother.

For example: ProductID = 26
When I add thirteen products with ID 26, I dont want them all seperate, but just the quantity to 13.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

after cart->init():

```
$productId = $observer->getProduct()->getId();
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
if (! $quote->hasProductId($productId)) {
     //normal add
}else{
    $item = $quote->getItemByProduct($observer->getProduct());
    $itemQty = $item->getQty();
    $item->setQty($itemQty+1);
    $item->save();
}
```

I didn't try it. Let's tell me if this work.